# Having attributetype in new objectclass with

Tags: ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

I am new to LDAP, I have created a new `objectclass` as below:

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.4.1.7
        NAME 'functions'
        DESC 'Admin functions'
        EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.4.2.3
        NAME 'adminFunctionsGroup'
        DESC 'Admin functions group'
        SUP top
        STRUCTURAL
        MUST ( cn ) )
```

Now I need to create a new `objectclass` to have an `attributetype` to refer to one of its siblings in this case `adminFunctionsGroup` as they both have the parent `top.

I tried to create it as below but getting an error:

```
AttributeType not found: adminFunctionsGroup
```

Attempt:

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.4.1.8
        NAME 'adminFunctions'
        DESC 'Admin functions'
        EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.4.1.9
        NAME 'adminGroups'
        DESC 'Admin groups'
        EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
        SUP adminFunctionsGroup
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.4.2.1
        NAME 'User'
        DESC 'user object'
        SUP top
        STRUCTURAL
        MUST ( cn $ adminGroups )
                MAY adminFunctions )
```

Is there any other way of referencing a sibling in an `objectclass` definition?

Comment: You have "`MAY adminFunctions`" in the `User` objectClass. Where is `adminFunctions` defined?

Comment: I thought it's gonna be easier here if I remove some extra attributes, I changed it to the original